# Compare two numpy arrays and insert nans

Tags: python, numpy

I have two numpy arrays with the dimensions (120, 360), one of the arrays consists of integers and zeros the second consists of floats. I want to replace the values of the second array with nans everywhere there is an integer in the first array. Is there an easy and efficient way to do this?

Also I'd like to replace the integers in the first array with nans and change zeros to ones. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve this easily with logical indexing into the array,

```
arr2[ arr1 != 0 ] = numpy.NaN
```

However integer arrays don't support NaNs so you'd have to convert your first array to a float array, i.e.

```
arr1 = arr1.astype(float)
arr1[arr1 != 0.0] = numpy.NaN
arr1[arr1 == 0.0] = 1.0
```

Comment: thanks, is there a similar way to do this for the second part without creating a new array?

Comment: @pter: where is a new array created? You still only have `arr1` and `arr2`

Comment: (Though admittedly the `astype` statement creates a copy of arr1, but we then assign that to arr1 again)

Comment: Right, I typed that before you edited it. Thanks again, this worked great.

Answer (score 2):

Setup the arrays:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = np.array([[1,0],[0,4]], dtype=int)
>>> y = np.array([[1.1, 2.2],[3.3, 4.4]], dtype=float)
```

You can easily set the second array to nan where you want, like this:

```
>>> y[x != 0] = np.nan
>>> y
array([[ nan,  2.2],
       [ 3.3,  nan]])
```

Then convert the first array to floats (since NaN is not an integer) and set the values you want:

```
>>> x = x.astype(float)
>>> x[x != 0] = np.nan
>>> x[x == 0] = 1
>>> x
array([[ nan,   1.],
       [  1.,  nan]])
```

Answer (score 0):

As a comment on the previous answers, I don't think comparing floats with `==` is that a good idea, and I think some operations are wasted. What about creating a temporary array `mask = (X != 0)` and use it as index ?

```
>>> X = X.astype(float)
>>> X[~mask] = np.nan
>>> X[mask] = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your purpose of replacing values with NaNs, but you may want to consider using numpy's masked arrays instead (similar to Pierre's answer, but numpy has builtin mask support!):

```
import numpy.ma
# mask out values when there is a non-zero integer in arr1
arr2 = numpy.ma.masked_array(arr2, mask=arr1)
# mask out values in arr2 for non-zero integers, and set all remaining values (the zeros) to 1
arr1 = numpy.ma(arr1, mask=(arr1 != 0))
arr1[~arr1.mask] = 1
```

No integer to float conversion needed, and this allows you to use a lot of numpy's functionality without getting into problems. E.g., calculating the mean of an array with NaNs is certainly a bad idea, with a masked array, this is no problem.